# How to use distinct with skip and limit in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement where i need to use distinct with skip and limit and i have googled a lot for this but found nothing useful and as per some answers it is not supported with old version spring data mongodb and in the newer version is there any way to use this or is there any solution to achieve distinct with skip and limit with aggregation framework

Answer (score 1):

I have not added distinct but used skip, limit with aggregation

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("goalId").is(goal.getId())), skip((long) request.getPage() * request.getSize()),limit(request.getSize()));  
final AggregationResults<ActivityHistory> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, ActivityHistory.class, ActivityHistory.class);
List<ActivityHistory> activityHistoryList = results.getMappedResults();
```